# Get 13 weeks moving average on Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to get the last 13 week moving average of my inventory and sales columns (I have thousands of rows but I wanna get the last 13 week moving average from the recent going back since there's new data every week).

I have the weekno there (that is setup as YYYY-WEEKNO).

Anyone has any idea on how I can do this in **Oracle SQL**?

```
| weekno | inventory | sales |   
| 202111| 5    | 78 |   
| 202110| 6    | 50 |    
| 202109| 3    | 80 |   
| 202108| 2    | 75 |   
| 202107| 5    | 33 |    
| 202106| 8    | 77 |   
| 202105| 3    | 80 |    
| 202104| 2    | 75 | 
| 202103| 5    | 33 |   
| 202102| 8    | 77 |    
| 202101| 8    | 77 |    
| 202053| 2    | 75 |    
| 202052| 5    | 33 |  
| 202051| 8    | 77 |  
| 202050| 8    | 77 |
```

..... and so on

Comment: Do you have always exactly one week per record, i.e. no duplicates or gaps?

Answer (score 3):

You can use window functions.  Assuming you have data for every week:

```
select t.*,
       avg(inventory) over (order by weekno rows between 12 preceding and current row),
       avg(sales) over (order by weekno rows between 12 preceding and current row)
from t;
```

Note:  This assumes that previous 13 weeks includes the current week.  If not, you would use:

```
 avg(sales) over (order by weekno rows between 13 preceding and 1 preceding)
```

Comment: Awesome. Do you think there are other ways to do this? Like a more optimized / faster way to query?

Comment: @KateLara It's a plain select. How do you think it could be any faster?

Comment: So I was thinking like doing a nested query with FISCAL_WEEK or DAY table on Oracle SQL like a: AVG(CASE WHEN weekno = WHERE DATE_DT >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 91 AND DATE_DT <= trunc(SYSDATE) -7;)

Comment: ^ Not 100% on the SQL statement that I just gave but something like that? I'm not sure if it's slower tho.

Comment: @itskcl . . . A window function should be faster, often much faster* than a subquery.

Comment: I see, I actually tried the codes you sent it's also slow and I haven't seen any results yet. I have huge volume of data. Any tips on how I can quickly check if it works? Like limit rows or something on SQL developer? I'm trying to create a table out of this ^

Comment: @itskcl . . . You can create a test table with  a small number of rows from your larger table.

Comment: How many rows you have in the base table,  if you have a lot , then you can built a Oracle Materialized view  with weekly data and then select the data for the last 13 week.

Comment: Hi @hkandpal I have millions of rows. How would you start off with that? What syntax can I use?

Comment: I've been looking at documentations but I'm really not sure where to start from this table I have ^.

Comment: Check this link, it has an example https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:14583471034798